# notification setLargeIcon and setSmallIcon not working

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to `setLargeIcon` & `setSmallIcon` but it's not working.
Notification is showing but default android icon is being shown.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "my_channel_01")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.app_icon))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
                .setContentText("Notification Text")
                //.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
```

Comment: did you solve it? i'm stuck with the same thing :(